# Socket connected via the Internet but BufferedReader is not recieving any lines

Tags: java, sockets, dns, global

I tried to make a basic Socket communication using BufferedReader and BufferedWriter which works without any problems using "localhost" or connecting in a local network with 2 PCs using the same router. The step that's making me trouble is the **connection via the Internet**. I have set up a **free domain at selfhost**, and also added that domain to my router's **dynamic dns** settings and added an **NAT** for the used port.
After that I was able to make the ServerSocket **accept** the request via that domain, and were able to use the write(string + "\n") and flush() methods of the Sockets on both sides, but the BufferedReader **didn't recieve** any of these messages and throws an Exception because "null" is returned after a few seconds. The same occured when using the global ip, only the local and hamachii ips have worked yet.
I already opened the port in my **firewall** for any TCP-usage and deactivated any **Anti-Virus software** on my computer that could block it for a while, but nothing changed.
Both Sockets return true for the **isConnected()** method but the when I use the global ip / domain the **ready() method return false the whole time**. I have really no idea what i causing the problem but i don't think that it has something to do with my firewall because else i guess i wouldn't even be able to connect, or there would be at least a one-way communication possible. Is it a special thing with java, that there is a different communication protocol when using global IPs? What is keeping the reader busy the whole time?

I would really appreciate if anyone has a constructive idea or someone has the same problem.

Basic Example:
When using ip = "globalhost" the console outputs "message"
When using ip = global-ip or selfhost-domain the Server sends the line and closes but the Client doesn't recieve anything.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      Socket client = new Socket (ip, 1034);
      InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
      System.out.println(reader.readLine());
      client.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
  }
}

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1034);
      Socket socket = server.accept();
      OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
      BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
      writer.write("message\n");
      writer.flush();
      server.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question with a code sample. Please post your code as an [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: have you tried using wireshark to determine if any messages reach your "server"?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  writer.write("message\r\n");
```